# Error 500 while running a Fluent NHibernate Project with Visual Studio 2015 for Mac

Tags: asp.net-mvc, macos, visual-studio-2015, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

So, I'm trying to run an ASP.NET MVC 5 with NHibernate and FluentNHibernate targeting SQL Server 2012 with Visual Studio 2015 for Mac and XSP Webserver, and it fails with the exception below. I'm using .NET Framework 4.5 and packages are updated to the very last version.

```
System.ArgumentNullException
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: type

Description: HTTP 500.Error processing request.
Details: Non-web exception. Exception origin (name of application or object): System.Core.
Exception stack trace:
  at System.Dynamic.Utils.ContractUtils.RequiresNotNull (System.Object value, System.String paramName) [0x00003] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-02/bockbuild-2017-02/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/external/corefx/src/Common/src/System/Dynamic/Utils/ContractUtils.cs:67 
  at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Convert (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression expression, System.Type type, System.Reflection.MethodInfo method) [0x0000b] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-02/bockbuild-2017-02/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/external/corefx/src/System.Linq.Expressions/src/System/Linq/Expressions/UnaryExpression.cs:780 
  at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Convert (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression expression, System.Type type) [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-02/bockbuild-2017-02/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/external/corefx/src/System.Linq.Expressions/src/System/Linq/Expressions/UnaryExpression.cs:763 
  at NHibernate.Util.DelegateHelper.BuildPropertySetter[T] (System.Type type, System.String propertyName) [0x00015] in <1c5d1dfd6b734554b068885679d8b49d>:0 
  at NHibernate.AdoNet.SqlClientSqlCommandSet..cctor () [0x00019] in <1c5d1dfd6b734554b068885679d8b49d>:0
```

Maybe this is a NHibernate or FluentNHibernate bug?

Comment: did you find out anything there? I think I have the same problem

Comment: Unfortunately, no... probably the best workaround should be add the source code of these libraries to the project and debug it myself, but I can't do that at this moment since I'm too late in my schedule...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added NHibenrate to the project and got a Socket Exception. As I just wanted to try out NHibernate I switched to a Win 10 machine and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've found a solution. Because of a bug or something, we need to configure the database with a batch size of zero to avoid this exception:

```
        return Fluently.Configure()

           .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2012.ConnectionString(
           x => x.FromConnectionStringWithKey("ConexaoBanco")).ShowSql())

            .Mappings(m =>
              m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<HomeController>())

           .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => cfg.SetProperty("adonet.batch_size", "0"))

           .BuildSessionFactory();
```

I should give proper credit to sta-blockhead for the solution: http://sta-blockhead.blogspot.com.br/2009/06/systemdatasqlclientsqlcommandset.html